# amp-base-carousel loop not wont loop through carousel

Tags: amp-html

Trying to adda a loop to amp-base-carousel, but when I click on either prev or next arrows there's no looping taking place. Once the carousel get's to the last image the arrow get's disabled.

```
 <amp-base-carousel  height="300" width="1100" layout="fixed" visible-count="(min-width:840px) 3, (min-width: 440px) 2, 1" advance-count="2" loop="true">
        <amp-img src="images/TR.png" width="400" height="300" alt="a sample image" layout="flex-item"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="images/horizon.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="another sample image" layout="flex-item"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="images/uncharted.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="and another sample image" layout="flex-item"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="images/ratchet.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="and another sample image" layout="flex-item"></amp-img>
    </amp-base-carousel>
```

Comment: This is an incomplete example. Where are the specifications for controlling the carousel? See AMP documentation for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply loop only with type="slides". Try this example, a tricky way to make carousel from slides:

```
<amp-base-carousel
    layout="responsive" // or fixed-height
    height="1"
    width="1"
    heights="500px"
    visible-count="(min-width: 1600px) 2, 1" // Magic 1
    snap="true" // Magic 2
    snap-align="center" // Magic 3
    snap-by="1"
    loop="true"
    slide="1"
>   
</amp-base-carousel>
```

And adjust width of child slide with CSS:

```
.inner-slide { 
    width: calc(100% - 6vw);
    margin-left: 3vw;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Note that with particular configuration there have to be at least 6 slides**